# extract a number starting from some fix number from a given string using Regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to extract a number from a string which is a mix of letters and numbers.
For example:

```
string1 = "1901920100153 abcx"
string2 = "123 1901920100159 abcdf"
string3 = "--> + - asdj 1901920100123 yuman"
```

now I want to extract only 13 digits number from the above strings which start from 1901920100(10 digits) and last three digits could be change like 1901920100153(13 digit), 1901920100159(13 digit), 1901920100123

I tried Regex expression
string.match(/(\d+)/) but it is extracting 123 from string2 which I doesn't want at all.
Please help finding me the regex expression. Thanks

Comment: Use `1901920100\d{3}` or `\b1901920100\d{3}\b`, see https://regex101.com/r/RapNnJ/1

Comment: Thank you so much, what does that \b for ?

Comment: `\b` is a word boundary.

Comment: Hey, if my string is like this "abc1901920100153mad" this expression returning null, Is there any way to extract from these types of strings also if number is attached with letters ?Thank you

Comment: Why? The regex (the first one) works, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/RapNnJ/2). Or do you mean you want `(?<!\d)1901920100\d{3}(?!\d)`? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/RapNnJ/3).

Comment: Ok working now, I was trying second one. How do I mark your answer correct, or do I answer my own question ?. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a certain number that starts with a fixed value and then has X amount of digits, you can use a basic pattern like

```
1901920100\d{3}
```

If you want to make sure there is no digit on both ends of the number, you can use

```
(?<!\d)1901920100\d{3}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/RapNnJ/2) and [demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/RapNnJ/3).

Since the second regex contains lookbehind that is still not universally supported by all JS environments, you can re-write it as `(?:^|\D)(1901920100\d{3})(?!\d)` and grab Group 1 values.

JavaScript demos:

```js
var strings = [ "1901920100153 abcx", "123 1901920100159 abcdf", "--> + - asdj 1901920100123 yuman" ];
var fixed_part = "1901920100";
var regex = new RegExp(fixed_part + "\\d{3}", "g");
for (var i=0; i<strings.length; i++) {
  console.log(strings[i], '=>', strings[i].match(regex));
}
```

ECMAScript 2018+ compliant regex with lookbehind demo:

```js
const strings = [ "1901920100153 abcx", "123 1901920100159 abcdf", "--> + - asdj 1901920100123 yuman" ];
const fixed_part = "1901920100";
const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`(?<!\d)${fixed_part}\d{3}(?!\d)`, "g");
for (var text of strings) {
    console.log(text, '=>', text.match(regex));
}
```